# Error while importing CSV File using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, csv

Currently I am trying to import a CSV file using the python extension in QGIS and I have run into a problem that I can not seem to solve.

I am trying to do a basic import of a CSV file from a python code I created (See below) and every time the file loads the values in my attribute table become re-arranged (see image).

When I load the file from the "Create a Layer from a Delimited Text File" option it loads without a problem.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
uri = "file:///D:/MLB Stadiums/Test_R2/Player_Files/Espinosa_2014.csv?
       delimiter=%ss&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "field_3", "field_4")
   vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Espinosa", "delimitedtext")
   caps =vlayer.dataProvider().capabilities()
```

Here is a comparison of what it should look like after import and what it does look like.

[image]

Does anyone know why it is rearranging the values?

Answer (score 4):

It's having problems with the letter `s`, because your code specifies that as a delimiter (`delimiter=%ss` is getting interpreted as `"," and "s"`). Try `delimiter=%s`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the format function of python if you have problems to format the string with %s. 
[Python Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Your uri would look something like:

```
uri = "file:///D:/MLB Stadiums/Test_R2/Player_Files/Espinosa_2014.csv?
   delimiter={delimiter}s&xField={field3}&yField={field4}".format(delimiter=",",
                                                                  field3="field_3", 
                                                                  field4="field_4")
```

Or the second s in %ss after the delimiter is too much in this case. If you need it like this you can use `"...delimiter=%s"%(",")+"s&xField..."` for example.